# How to get default Android timer expired ringtone?

Tags: android, timer, default, ringtone

I can get Android default alarm ringtone this way:

```
    Uri alarmRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alarmRingtoneUri);
    ringtone.play();
```

But there is no infomation how to get [this standard timer expired ringtone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tlce3.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Android OS does not have a timer expired ringtone, because the Android OS does not have a timer. Either that is from an app or it is from some modified version of Android.